# Javascript, regarding node.js: How can I make the code store, in an array, SQL values

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

So here I have a big problem: I need to create an array that stores an SQL value, in a json file (the code is below). The thing is, where do I declare the query, or what extra should I add to make it work properly? I have created the function viewMontadora, and it works normally when I run the server, listing all the car makers registered in SQL, with all their info. I'm still not very familiar with node.js.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/library'))
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Servidor online em 
http://localhost:${port}`)
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('pages/home')
})

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {

    function viewMontadora() {
        var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);
        conn.connect().then(function () {
            var req = new sql.Request(conn);
            req.query("SELECT * FROM VIEW_PRODUTOS").then(function (recordset) {
                res.contentType('application/json');
                res.send(JSON.stringify(recordset));
                console.log(recordset);
                conn.close();
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                conn.close();
            });
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    return viewMontadora();

})

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    res.render('pages/contact')
})

app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Obrigado por entrar em contato conosco, ' + req.body.name + '!Responderemos em breve!')
})

app.post('/client', (req, res) => {
        // Lista de Utilizadores
        var usersValid = [{
            username: 'SELECT [RazaoSocial] FROM [SITE].[dbo].[Clientes]',
            email: 'SELECT [Email] FROM [SITE].[dbo].[Clientes]'
        }, ];
        console.log(usersValid);
        var error = [{
            id: 1,
            ErrorLogin: 'Usuario não identificado'
        }];

        usersValid.push({
            username: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < usersValid.length; i++) {
            if (usersValid[i].username === req.body.name && usersValid[i].email ===
                req.body.email) {

                var dataClient = [{
                    nameClient: req.body.name,
                    emailClient: req.body.email,
                    imgClient: 'http://lmdsneto.000webhostapp.com/images/user.png'
                }]
                res.render('pages/client', {
                    dataClients: dataClient
                })
                //res.send('Bem vindo, ' + req.body.name + ' Email ' + 
                req.body.email
        } else {
            res.send(error);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you saying that the recordset result is not an array?

Comment: It is, that function works properly. I'm having issue with usersValid. What should I change? Should I create an extra function (usersValid())?

Comment: So in app.post('/client'... your trying to validate one or more users?

Comment: That's the thing. Since it will be a customer login page, it should handle multiple requests, but one by one, not a set of customer logins.

Answer (score 0):

On a high level you need to receive a email and password from the client Eg. Browser, then you need to confirm if that username and password exist in your db. if then do then you can say that they are a valid user.

So aside from security concerns about storing passwords in plain text you should be able to just simply do this: (Obviously just change any values for the user id that you need)

```
app.post('/client', (req, res) => {

    // place userInfo into an object
    var userInfo = {
        email: req.body.name,
        password: req.body.password
    };

    var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);

    conn.connect().then(function () {
        var req = new sql.Request(conn);
        req.query("SELECT * FROM FROM [SITE].[dbo].[Clientes] WHERE email = " +
            userInfo.email +
            " AND password = " +
            userInfo.password).then(function (selectedUser) {
            // if we have one selected user we know it is valid
            if (selectedUser.length === 1) {
                // user is valid

            } else {
                // user is not valid
            }
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Let me know if it works, or if you have any issues. and I can update the answer

Comment: After editing, it shows this error on the test: 
    TypeError: req.query is not a function
    at /home/ftp/ftpuser/projects_nodejs/OjiCRM/OjiCRM/server.js:62:28

Comment: The edited code is below:
    app.post('/client', (req, res) => {

    // Colocar informação do usuário num objeto:
    var userInfo = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email
    };

    // Checar se usuário e senha estão corretos:
    var selectedUser = req.query("SELECT * FROM FROM [SITE].[dbo].
    [Clientes] WHERE RazaoSocial = " + userInfo.email + " AND Email = " 
    + userInfo.email);

    // Se só houver um usuário, e este for válido
    if (selectedUser.length === 1) {
        // usuário válido

Comment: sorry the name you used in the about route conflicts with express you should name the variable `db` as I did in the updated answer

Comment: But the connection isn't declared as a variable... 
"ReferenceError: conn is not defined"
It is still different though! From the other function: 
var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);

Comment: BTW, thanks @TyBourque. I've just started working with node.js, so you can see I'm a bit confused.

Comment: What lib are you using to connect node to your db? I'll make the answer very specific then

Comment: mssql and fs libs

Comment: So what we need to do is just implement it the way you did in your other function and it should work assuming that function works and you have dbConfig as a global variable somewhere I made the changes

Comment: I'll try it out! Maybe this time it will work! Thanks! Do you have any node.js course you recommend?

Comment: Not in particular YouTube is a good free resource. Also don't forget to mark the question as solved if it worked.

Comment: The thing is, I tested but it didn't actually work correctly. It doesn't verify any info, be it name or email...